# install an old version of dplyr (0.12) in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wondering if there is a way to install (or just use) and old version of dplyr.  I wrote some code in version 0.12 and since then "do()" has been overhauled and it's breaking my code all over the place.  I will update things to fix it, but in the mean time i'd like to get my code to run.  Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/

Comment: thank you, i can install it from source, but i don't know what version of R it works with... any way to find out what verison of R it depends on?

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/v0.1.2/DESCRIPTION#L13

Comment: thank you, i am getting this error now Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also download the zip of the package from CRAN and then install the package from the local zip file. This way you can download an older version (if still available on CRAN or you can find it somewhere else) and install that. Both RStudio and RGui have specific buttons that help you with this. As for the specific function call, I believe it doesn't have to be through devtools, but it can also be something like this

```
install.packages("path_to_your_package.zip", repos = NULL)
```

And it will install it to your default R library folder.

Answer (score 10):

Use `install_github` function from `devtools` package for this:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr@v0.1.2")
```

Also you can use [CRAN archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/) and `install_url` function:

```
devtools::install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.1.2.tar.gz")
```